# LSTM model can not predict properly but works on the test samples

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I have an LSTM model as follow:

The problem is that:
It can work on the X_test.

However, when I choose a part of X_test and  want to predict the next `N` ahead point, it can not work.

Finally, I want to plot a figure like the following. Could you please help me with that?

Could you help me with that?
I also provide the function for creating the X_train and test for the different test.
Thanks a million

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM

X_train = np.random.rand(100, 5, 2)
Y_train = np.random.rand(100, 1)
X_test  = np.random.rand(10, 5, 2)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],      X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(Y_train.shape[1], kernel_regularizer='l2'))
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=200,    validation_split=0.1,verbose=1)

prediction = model.predict(X_test) #test on X_test
```

Creating X_train and Y_traing and test:

```
def create_X_Y(ts, lag):
    X, Y = [], []
    if len(ts) - lag <= 0:
        X.append(ts)
    else:
        for i in range(len(ts) - lag):
            Y.append(ts[i + lag])
            X.append(ts[i:(i + lag)])
    X, Y = np.array(X), np.array(Y)
    X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
    return X, Y
```

This is the code which I am using for the predict the N ahead.

```
def create_data_n_ahead(y, use_last_n):
    if use_last_n is not None:
            y = y[-use_last_n:]
    X, Y = create_X_Y(y, lag)
    return X, Y
def predict_n_ahead(y, n_ahead):
    X, _ = create_data_n_ahead(y, lag)
    yhat = []
    for _ in range(n_ahead):
        fc = model.predict(X)
        yhat.append(fc)
        X = np.append(X, fc)
        X = np.delete(X, 0)
        X = np.reshape(X, (1, len(X), 1))
    return yhat
```

This is when I want to predict the 80 point ahead

[image: This is when I want to predict the 80 point ahead]

This is when I feed the X_test to the model:

[image: This is when I feed the X_test to the model]

Comment: Please take the time to label each image with an explanation of what it represents. It's hard to understand which part of the text refers to each image. From inspecting the plots, it looks like the model mainly remembers the previous step with some long-term decay. So what I think is happening is that the bottom plot shows that the model knows how to reproduce the previous step, while the middle plot remembers the first time step, and decays afterwards. This might be related to the non-stationarity of the data -- e.g. a good predictor of tomorrow's temperature is today's temperature.

Comment: @sycorax Thanks. I've just updated the question.

Comment: @sycorax thank you. But, here is one model with a constant lag value. I did not change anything in the model.